# Is the "char in string" python method efficient?

Tags: python, python-3.x, substring

Is Python built in method of finding substring efficient enough for finding char match? I read somewhere, that even if it finds match, it continues to cycle through the string till the very end, but can't find relative info on internet. 
Is this method actually efficient in Python 3.7 or maybe I should write my own function like this (or maybe there is more efficient way?):

```
def char_in_str(char:str, string:str):
    for i in string:
        if i == char:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: The `in` operator short circuits. It does what your function above basically does.

Comment: "I read somewhere" is not a good source for your claim. Ask yourself: Why would the people who write the Python interpreter implement a slow approach if a better way exists?

Answer (score 2):

That will definitely short-circuit (as soon as you hit the `return`, the function is done; it *can't* keep looking). Mind you, the efficient implementation would be just:

```
def char_in_str(char:str, string:str):
    return char in string
```

or if you only want it to succeed when `char` is in fact a length one string:

```
def char_in_str(char:str, string:str):
    return len(char) == 1 and char in string
```

In both cases, the `in` operator short-circuits when it finds a match, and unlike your code, the implementation is implemented more efficiently within the interpreter itself (on CPython, in C) than a Python level loop could be.